# Documents access to limited group of users (related to Account)

Tags: account, sharing, contentdocument, access, libraries

I have a requirement

- There are a group of users who can upload documents on Account (possibly public group)

However, the documents uploaded should only be accessible to that group of users and not even to the Account Owner.

I am thinking somehow libraries may help but not 100% sure.

Has anyone used a similar set up or is aware of a solution?

Thanks

Comment: relevant doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Comment: Hi @cropredy, Are you referring Content Document link as a way to implement the use case?

Comment: when you say "documents", I assumed you meant SFDC Files, not SFDC Documents

Comment: Can I hide the visibility of Content Document Link to hide the records from owner of an  account?

Comment: Community best practices are for the poster to do some research, try some things, and [edit] the OP where/when you are stuck for tangible results.